# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Materials Modeling's [first moderator election](https://materials.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three moderators are:

[image: Tyberius] [image: I. Camps] [image: Thomas]

Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! Thanks as well to all of the nominees - your interest in participating this site is what will keep this site healthy and growing. We hope you all continue to work together to build this new site!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://materials.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4915953063165952/0).

Answer (score 12):

Congrats [Tyberius](https://materials.stackexchange.com/users/7/tyberius) and [I.Camps](https://materials.stackexchange.com/users/24/i-camps).

Special thanks to other candidates [etienne_ip](https://materials.stackexchange.com/users/175/etienne-ip), [taciteloquence](http://taciteloquence), [TheSimpliFire](https://materials.stackexchange.com/users/35/thesimplifire) and [Alone Programmer](https://materials.stackexchange.com/users/37/alone-programmer).

Also a big thanks to [all](https://materials.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent) who voted and supported us. Thank you for your trust and I hope that we will be able to fulfill your expectations.

Comment: I second this! The group will be in good hands!